# Can I release under AGPL a program that uses a GPL library?

Tags: license-compatibility, gpl-3, agpl-3.0

I just wrote a program that embeds and uses a GNU-GPL library (*GPLv3 or at your discretion any later version*).

Can I release my program under the GNU AGPL v3 license?

Comment: This is an example for a question where I would like to see proof of research - or some more comments requesting that.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you can use a GPL3 library [1] in an AGPL3 program [2]. You can also cut-and-paste GPL3 code into an AGPL3 program.

> Both the ordinary GNU GPL, version 3, and the GNU Affero GPL have text allowing you to link together modules under these two licenses in one program.

(from https://www.gnu.org/licenses/why-affero-gpl.html )

Obviously, you should make the code for both portions available from your AGPL program, and include all appropriate copyright notices, as you normally would with GPL/AGPL code.

---

In fact, you can even use an *AGPL library* in a *GPL program*, as long as you make the AGPL code available whenever its conditions are met (e.g. from behind a GPL-licensed content management system).

> Notwithstanding any other provision of this License, you have permission to link or combine any covered work with a work licensed under version 3 of the GNU General Public License into a single combined work, and to convey the resulting work. The terms of this License will continue to apply to the part which is the covered work, but the work with which it is combined will remain governed by version 3 of the GNU General Public License.

(from http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html )

---

[1] Or GPL2+ library or GPL3+ library

[2] Or AGPL3+ program

Comment: How does this play together with section 10 *"You may not impose any further restrictions on the exercise of the rights granted or affirmed under this License."* Doesn't the AGPL restrict the right to run a modified version of the program on a remote server *without* publishing the source code? Section 13 of the AGPL is an additional commitment however I'm not sure if it can also be interpreted as restricting rights which are granted by the GPL.

Comment: @a_guest You are right that the AGPL could not ordinarily interfere with the GPL's section 10. However, the GPL itself makes this possible by an explicit permission in the GPL's own section 13: "*Notwithstanding any other provision of this License, you have permission to link or combine any covered work with a work licensed under version 3 of the GNU Affero General Public License into a single combined work...*" -- In other words, the GPLv3 and AGPLv3 both have section 13's that operate in explicit coordination with one another to make such combinations possible.